# Flash AS3 Parameter Child Must Be Non-Null

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, null

I'm having this error in which I have a Main Menu scene, an Options scene, and a game scene. I have a external file which holds all the public variables that I need between scenes. In the game, there is a picture of water in the background which is purely decorative and doesn't do anything, the only time I use it in code is when I'm moving it to the back so other platforms can be positioned on top of it by using the code:

```
setChildIndex(gfxWater, 1);
```

This used to work before I put the options scene in, and still does, provided I don't go to the options scene. Even if I don't touch anything on the options scene, simply going there causes this line to throw a "Parameter Child must be non-null" error. I tried to trace gfxWater right beforehand, but just got null. I simply dragged the water onto the screen to create it and gave it the instance name gfxWater. I don't understand how that could be null, its still there even when this line breaks, it's just on top of everything else.

In the options menu I am not doing anything with the water, I'm only changing variables such as whether or not to play music or sound effects, stuff like that. Nothing relative to  the water. The only thing that I can think of that might be causing a problem is that I used a custom font in the options scene, so I had to create the text in AS3. Before I transition back to the main menu though, I make sure to remove the text. That code is here:

```
//This Removes The Text
for (m = 0; m < optionsTextArray.length; m++){
    optionsTextArray[m].parent.removeChild(optionsTextArray[m]);
}
optionsTextArray.splice(0, optionsTextArray);

//This Hides The Images
soundFxCheck.parent.removeChild(soundFxCheck);
soundFxX.parent.removeChild(soundFxX);
musicCheck.parent.removeChild(musicCheck);
musicX.parent.removeChild(musicX);
codeCheck.parent.removeChild(codeCheck);
codeX.parent.removeChild(codeX);

//This Transitions To The Main Menu
gotoAndPlay("menuStart", "Main_Menu");
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Also just for reference I am using AS3 on CS3 (Sorry, my school is a little out of date). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the error magically fixed itself, I just ignored it for a while working on other sections, and when I came back to it, it worked. I don't know what I did, or why it is working now, but I guess cursing at computers does work occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error you'll get if you effectively try to do this:

```
removeChild(null);
```

Which means that one of the properties you're parsing through `removeChild()` doesn't have a value.

Because you haven't supplied any code that shows how your objects are being added and so on, it's hard to determine where exactly in the application your issue is; everything I see above seems OK  to me.

Comment: There was no code to add the water, I just dragged it onscreen and gave it a name. Even when the line breaks the water is still there, perfectly fine, just in front of all the platforms when it should be behind. But there was no code that put the water onscreen, I just did it in the designer.

Comment: Hm, the only thing I can think of here is that you might be calling that code before the items actually exist in code. What happens if you try trace(thing) or trace(this["thing"]);

Comment: If I do it immediately before the setChildIndex line, i get null. Somehow it doesn't exist, but I would think AS would be smart enough to create the objects before running the code. Then again, computers aren't too bright.

Comment: This will only work if the code is placed in the same container as the objects you're trying to access. I assume this is the case?

Comment: You're gonna have to define container. The code is in the same scene but a different layer, I have the code separated by its purpose. All the code related to the player goes in one layer, all the code for startup and keycode goes in another (that's where the setChildIndex line is). Although the water is in a layer completely all its own, no code or objects are together with it.

Comment: Basically your code needs to be on the same frame as the objects you're trying to access.

Comment: Yes, the code is on the same frame as the water object. The entire game scene is only one frame.

Comment: I did that earlier, and while that did circumvent the error, it also disabled that line entirely, putting the water on top of everything else, making it cover up half the platforms. That does stop the error, but it defeats the purpose of having that line there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dragging it from the library why not add it with code?  That way you know it exists the the right scope.

You'll need to go into the properties of the waterfall movieclip in the library and set it to Export for Actionscript, and assign it a name (lets assume WaterFall).  Then:

```
var waterfall:WaterFall = new WaterFall();
this.addChildAt(waterfall,0);
```

Now you shouldn't need to adjust its depth again because it is on the bottom depth and any other objects will be added above it, unless they specifically target depth 0 themselves.